# Putting a pointer as a value in a method call [python]

Tags: python

I'm trying to have a function where I can put in a list and a pointer, and have it apply that pointer to the objects in the list to give me the object with the lowest value of that pointer.

```
def GetLowest(ListObject,Value):

    ObjectX=ListObject[0]

    for i in ListObject:

        if i.Value<=ObjectX.Value:

            ObjectX=i

    return ObjectX
```

Then I could do things like (assuming I have lists of these objects) `GetLowest(Rectangles,Area)` and have it check the area of each rectangle. Or maybe something more complex like `GetLowest(Backpacks,Wearer.ShoeSize)`.

I'm going to want to use this in a few places around my program.
Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: I don't think ordinary Python has pointers. Do you mean attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you would like to use the builtin [`min`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function.  `min` takes an iterable (e.g. a list) and returns the minumum element.  You can also give it a `key` function which is called to do the comparison.

e.g.:

```
smallest_rectangle = min(list_of_rectangles,key=lambda rect:rect.area)
backpack_with_small_shoes = min(backpacks,key=lambda b: b.wearer.shoe_size)
```

The various functions in the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) module are really useful here too.  For example, the first statement above could be written as:

```
from operator import attrgetter
smallest_rectangle = min(list_of_rectangles,key=attrgetter('area'))
```

Comment: I figured there was probably some built-in function I was missing. I just tried the min thing and it worked first try. Thanks a million!